# Ffmpeg stream problems with buffer data

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

my code is not working. I cannot conversion. how can I fix?

readable event working but Error output is

> data undefined

```
try {

    const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./ses.webm');

    const command = childProcess.spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i', 'pipe:0', '-c:a', 'aac', 'pipe:1']);

    readStream.pipe(command.stdin);
    command.stdout.on('readable', (a) => {
      console.log('data', a)
    });

    command.on('data', (code) => {
      console.log(`ffmpeg işlemi tamamlandı. Çıkış kodu: ${code}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
```